How to make Jenkins work on local computers when it is placed in a counter on the server
I have prepared a pipeline to help the Help Desk install certain applications on the computers they are replacing. However, by default, Jenkins runs on the server and, obviously, pipeline does not execute.
How to make Help Desk users run Jenkins and then select pipeline and execute it to automate the process of installing certain applications?
I have created Pipeline, but I don't know how to make it work on local computers in the network, and not on the server where Jenkins is located.

I'm not sure Jenkins is the best tool for an IT administration task like this. To pull this off, you need to remotely (or otherwise) log into the network computer and set it up as a slave pointing at your Jenkins server, then modify the Jenkins jobs so that they run on each slave. Or you could use SSH to remotely execute the commands but it's still not a very straightforward approach.
If the network machines are things like other servers, consider using tools like puppet or chef, which are specifically built for this. If they are local user machines then it's a different case entirely and you need to use vendor specific solutions for that.
